# Html Json parse to android listview

Tags: android, json, listview, get

How to parse JSON in listview

```
 {
   "about": [
          { "id":"1",
            "aboutus": " <p><b>Das CARE-Komplett-Paket für Menschen inNot</b></p> <p>Schnell, nachhaltig und durchdacht, das ist das moderne CARE-Paket. CARE ist überzeugt, dass umfassende Hilfe von drei Seiten notwendig ist, um die weltweite Armut Schritt für Schritt zu verringern. Deswegen hat CARE sich seit seiner Gründung 1945 und dem Abwurf der ersten CARE-Pakete über Berlin weiter entwickelt. Heute steckt im CARE-Paket weit mehr als Zucker und Mehl. Heute bietet die Organisation in 70 der ärmsten Länder der Welt ein Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not.</p><p><b>Das Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not enthält:</b></p>*sofortige Nothilfe nach Katastrophen<br><br>*langfristige Entwicklungszusammenarbeit<br><br>*Schutz der Menschenrechte<br><br>"
          }
            ]
}
```

Comment: textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(aboutus)); it will give html format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONObject json_about = new JSONObject(your_json_string);
JSONArray json_about_list = json_about.getJSONArray("about");
```

Use the `json_about_list` to your custom listview adapter

To get each object

```
JSONObject about_object = json_about_list.get(index);
String id = about_object.getString("id");
String aboutus = about_object.getString("aboutus");
```

Comment: String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
      String aboutus = c.getString(TAG_ABOUT_US);
     
      
      
      HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

       key => value
      contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
      contact.put(TAG_ABOUT_US, aboutus);
      
      aboutList.add(contact);

Comment: but problem is .
output in textview is
<p><b>Das CARE-Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not</b></p>  <p>Schnell, nachhaltig und durchdacht, das ist das moderne CARE-Paket. CARE ist überzeugt, dass umfassende Hilfe von drei Seiten notwendig ist, um die weltweite Armut Schritt für Schritt zu verringern. Deswegen hat CARE sich seit seiner Gründung 1945 und dem Abwurf der ersten CARE-Pakete über Berlin weiter entwickelt. Heute steckt im CARE-Paket weit mehr als Zucker und Mehl. Heute bietet die Organisation in 70 der ärmsten Länder der Welt ein Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not.</p><p><b>....

Comment: that's a different question :)